# __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType) I don't even where is the problem

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I was making which user allowed to do what and which doesn't allowed by watching a video series. After I did something, which I don't know, I couldn't delete one user. Then I added one more user to see could I delete that one. First I added one user on admin panel then I deleted it, it worked. But when I tried to add one user with register page I couldn't delete it. Then I looked the customer's on admin panel and I couldn't see the name there was '-' instead of the name of user.

decoraters.py

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse

def unauthenticated_user(view_func):
    def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('home')
    
        return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper_func

def allowed_users(allowed_roles=[]):
    def decorator(view_func):
        def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
            group = None
            if request.user.groups.exists():
                group = request.user.groups.all()[0].name
            if group in allowed_roles:
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                return HttpResponse('You are not autherized to view this page')
        return wrapper_func
    return decorator


def admin_only(view_func):
    def wrapper_function(request, *args, **kwargs):
        group = None

        if request.user.groups.exists():
            group = request.user.groups.all()[0].name

        if group == "customer":
            return redirect('user')
        if group == "admin":
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    
    return wrapper_function
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    phone = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True)
    profile_pic= models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
def registerPage(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = CreateUserForm()
        if request.method =="POST":
            form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                user = form.save()
                username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')

                group = Group.objects.get(name='customer')
                user.groups.add(group)
                Customer.objects.create(
                    user = user,
                )

                messages.success(request, 'Account was created for ' + username)
                return redirect('/login')

        context = {'form':form}
        return render(request,'register.html',context)
    
@unauthenticated_user
def loginPage(request):
    if request.method =="POST":
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password =password)

        if user is not None:
             login(request, user)
             return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'Username or password is incorrect')        
    context = {}
    return render(request,'login.html',context)
```

I do not even know what or where is the problem I hope someone can help me to fix it.

Comment: Are you sure you have only one model, `Customer` in your entire project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string method is the cause of the issue as the error suggests.Probably you have a Customer record without a name so it's empty. You will need to  change:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

To:

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.name)
```